# Django - How to iterate and inspect each choice for a ModelChoiceField in the template code

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a form (edited for brevity) as follows:

```
class InteractionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Each object within this queryset is a model object of type InteractionChoice
        choices_qs = interaction.interactionchoice_set.all()

        self.fields['choices'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                                    queryset=choices_qs,
```

The `InteractionChoice` model looks like:

```
class InteractionChoice(models.Model):
    interaction = models.ForeignKey(Interaction)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

An instance of `InteractionForm` is passed from a view to a template and rendered via:

```
{{ form.choices }}
```

My question is whether there is a way to iterate over each choice in my template and access one of its properties -- specifically, the `is_answer` property defined in `InteractionChoice`. The purpose being to customize how a choice is displayed if it is indeed the answer. More specifically, if `is_answer` is True, I'd possibly change the `class` attribute on the `<label>` for that choice.

Perhaps, I'm approaching this problem from the wrong direction. If anyone has pointers for alternative ideas, I'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**
Thinking about this more after @rczajka's response, I don't believe I can achieve what I'm hoping to do in the template code. Instead, if the purpose is to modify the tag's class attribute, I should perhaps be looking to subclass and override certain methods in `forms.widgets.RadioInput`, `forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer`, and `forms.widgets.RadioSelect`. I'll dig into this more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with one solution that addresses this problem. It's hackish, to say the least, but it's the only approach I've thought of that works thus far without a lot of back-end changes to my existing design.

My approach stemmed from [this article](http://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2010/01/subclass-django-forms-widgets-radiofieldrenderer-and-django-forms-widgets-radioselect-for-custom-rendering-of-individual-choices/) on subclassing `RadioFieldRenderer' and 'RadioSelect'.

In the `__unicode__` method for an `InteractionChoice` model, I return:

```
return self.name + "_" + str(self.is_answer)
```

which is the value used for a radio button's label (amongst other things). I then subclassed `forms.widgets.RadioInput`, `forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer`, and `forms.widgets.RadioSelect`.

For the custom RadioInput class, I overrode its `__unicode__` method to include logic to append a `class` string – whose value is ultimately dictated by the string returned from the **unicode** method in `InteractionChoice` – to the `<label>` tag string it returns.

For the custom RadioFieldRenderer class, I overrode `__iter__` and `__getitem__` to use the custom RadioInput class.

For the custom RadioSelect class, I overrode the `renderer` property to use my custom radio field renderer.

This is obviously far from an ideal solution. Hopefully, a better one will arise.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem but solved it in a different way.

[How to get ModelChoiceField instances in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300685/how-to-get-modelchoicefield-instances-in-the-template/10301239#10301239)

Iterating over the field's queryset property.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. It says so here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield:

> The **unicode** method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field's choices; to provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, rczajka. However, that only changes the label's string value, which is not what I want. I should have been more specific in my question in that I'm not looking to modify the string that's shown to the user but ultimately alter the class attribute on the <label> so that I can change its styling via CSS down the road.

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 3.2, you can iterate over the choices in templates. The [RadioSelect widget docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) state that you can loop over `RadioSelect` generated markup

> For more granular control over the generated markup, you can loop over the radio buttons in the template.

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```html
<ul>
 {% for choice in form.choices %}
   <li>{{ choice }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```