# Django: ModelMultipleChoiceField multi level

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have used `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True, is_active=True))
groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Group.objects.all(),
    required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Category.objects.filter(is_root=True),
    required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('name', 'title', 'url', 'image', 'desc', 'content', 'start', 'pinHome', 'pinNation', 'pinSchool', 'owner', 'poster', 'groups', 'categories')
```

and my Category model has

```
class Category(models.Model):
     parents = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, related_name='childs', symmetrical=False)
```

my template like that

```
{% for category in form.categories %}
     <label>
         {{category}}
         {% for childs in category.childs.all %}
              {{childs}}
         {% endfor %}
     </label>
 {% endfor %}
```

How can I access "children" of category on template. I have tried `{{category.childs.all}}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post a [minimum, verifiable, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no enough enough information here to help you.

Comment: i have updated, any idea for this pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ModelChoiceField instances in the template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300685/how-to-get-modelchoicefield-instances-in-the-template)

Comment: it's not work for me